# How to prove that this problem is NP Complete

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np, traveling-salesman, vertex-cover

I have a problem set about NP Completeness proofs and I'm struggling to approach this problem:

An organizer would like to arrange all the participants in a
circle where neighboring two students must have taken the same class last semester.

How to prove that this is an NP complete problem?

Any hints/tip would be very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Can you credit the original source where you encountered this task?

Comment: What did you try? What progress have you made?  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 4):

- Same class last semester: an edge between two vertices.
- Students in a circle: an hamiltonian cycle.

I think you should be able to do the rest.